# Unable to get JNIEnv* value in arbitrary context

Tags: android, c, java-native-interface, android-ndk

I have an issue with the NDK.

In my JNI_OnLoad method, I cache the JavaVm pointer, the class that called the method, and a method id which I use later on:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *jvm, void *reserved){
    JNIEnv *env;
    cachedJVM = jvm;
    if((*jvm)->GetEnv(jvm, (void**)&env, JNI_VERSION_1_6)){
        LOG_ERROR("Could not get JNIEnv*");
        return JNI_ERR;
    }
    javaClass = (*env)->FindClass(env, "org/test/opensl/AudioProcessor");
    if(javaClass == NULL){
        LOG_ERROR("Could not get java class");
        return JNI_ERR;
    }
    javaCallbackMID = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, javaClass, "enqueueAudio", "([B)V");
    if(javaCallbackMID == NULL){
        LOG_ERROR("Could not get method identifier");
        return JNI_ERR;
    }
    return JNI_VERSION_1_6;
}
```

I have a small utility method defined as follows that should get me a pointer to the JNIEnv:

```
JNIEnv* JNU_GetEnv(){
    JNIEnv* env;
    (*cachedJVM)->GetEnv(cachedJVM, (void**)&env, JNI_VERSION_1_6);
    return env;
}
```

And finally, I have a callback from an OpenSL ES `SLAndroidSimpleBufferQueueItf` which I want to handle the recorded audio from a `SLRecordItf`:

```
void recorderCallback(SLAndroidSimpleBufferQueueItf bq, void *context){
    SLresult result;
    JNIEnv* env;
    recorderContext* thisContext = (recorderContext*)context;
    env = JNU_GetEnv();
    if(env == NULL){
        LOG_ERROR("Could not get JNIEnv*");
        return;
    }
    jbyteArray data = (*env)->NewByteArray(env, MAX_PACKET_SIZE);
    if(data == NULL){
        LOG_ERROR("No memory could be allocated for buffer");
        return;
    }
    (*env)->SetByteArrayRegion(env, data, 0, MAX_PACKET_SIZE, recorderBuffer);
    (*env)->CallByteMethodA(env, thisContext->caller, javaCallbackMID, data);
    (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, data);
    result = (*bq)->Enqueue(bq, recorderBuffer,
                            RECORDER_FRAMES * sizeof(jbyte));
    checkError(result, "Unable to enqueue new buffer");
}
```

Where the context parameter for the callback method only holds a reference to the object that called the native method. It is a self defined struct like this:

```
typedef struct recorderContext{
    jobject caller;
} recorderContext;
```

However, every time I try to run this, I get the `"Could not get JNIEnv*"` error message from the callback method.

My question basically comes down to this: Why can I get a pointer to the JNIEnv in the JNI_OnLoad method, but not in the recorderCallback, as both use the same Java VM pointer to get the JNIEnv?

I need this callback to pass the recorded Audio back up to my Java layer for further processing...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Why can I get a pointer to the JNIEnv
>   in the JNI_OnLoad method, but not in
>   the recorderCallback, as both use the
>   same Java VM pointer to get the
>   JNIEnv?

Because the callback happens on some native thread, different from the VM thread which loads the library.  The JNI implementation maintains a `JNIEnv` per thread, and puts the pointer in thread-local storage.  It is only initialized for native threads which are attached to the VM.  You need to call `AttachCurrentThread()` (or more probably `AttachCurrentThreadAsDaemon()`) inside the callback to get a `JNIEnv` pointer valid for that thread.  This attaches the thread to the VM on the first call and is a nop thereafter.

See http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/invocation.html

*Caveat:* This answer assumes proper Java.  The problems you're seeing suggest that Dalvik behaves the same as the JVM.

Comment: Your answer helped me too. I initialized JNIEnv ptr in one VM thread and was thinking that the ptr can be used in another VM thread. But after several usages of the ptr I received SIGSEGV.

Comment: Helped me, too. But I got the problme that JNI_Onload() is not invoked (or even found), though the symbol is in my .so. I added JNI_Onload() inside extern "C" since i'm coming from c++.

Comment: Also see https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/jni.html where it has "you cannot share a JNIEnv between threads" in bold.