# Array of Object Array (2d arrays) JNI

Tags: java, arrays, java-native-interface

I'm struggling with creating a 2d array of my custom object type ShareStruct:

```
jobjectArray ret ;
jobjectArray ins ;
jobjectArray outs;

jclass myClass = (*env)->FindClass(env,"org/apache/s4/core/ShareStruct");
if (myClass==NULL) fprintf(stderr, "Class ShareStruct not found");

jclass myClassArray = (*env)->FindClass(env, "[Lorg/apache/s4/core/ShareStruct");
if (myClassArray==NULL) fprintf(stderr, "Class ShareStruct[] not found");

ins = (*env)->NewObjectArray(env, in, myClass, NULL);
outs = (*env)->NewObjectArray(env, out, myClass, NULL);
ret = (*env)->NewObjectArray(env, 2, myClassArray, NULL);
```

The first class loading works (the ShareStruct is fine), but the other one (trying to load a ShareStruct[] class) doesn't. I've tried both with and without the L but no luck. Any ideas? I'm new with JNI.

Thanks!

Comment: have updated my answer, did it help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This `jclass myClassArray = (*env)->FindClass(env, "[Lorg/apache/s4/core/ShareStruct");` is wrong. 
To create the array do  something like

```
 ret = (*env)->NewObjectArray(env,sizeOfArray,myClass,NULL);  
(*env)->SetObjectArrayElement( env, ret,index, sharedStructObj);
```

Here sharedStructObj will have to be created by newObject.
Section 3.3.5 of [JNI programmer's guide](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/download/jni.pdf) has a good related example

This is also nice [Create, populate and return 2D String array from native code (JNI/NDK)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6070679/create-populate-and-return-2d-string-array-from-native-code-jni-ndk)

**EDIT based on comment**

```
in = (*env)->NewObjectArray(env,sizeOfArray,myClass,NULL);
out = (*env)->NewObjectArray(env,sizeOfArray,myClass,NULL);
ret= (*env)->NewObjectArray(env,sizeOfArray,myClass,NULL);
(*env)->SetObjectArrayElement( env, ret,0, in); 
(*env)->SetObjectArrayElement( env, ret,1, out);
```

Comment: But I want to create an array of ShareStruct[], so the java equivalent would be ShareStruct[][].  I don't see how this code does that :(

Effectively, I want to do :

ShareStruct[] in;
ShareStruct[] out;
ShareStruct[][] ret ;

ret[0] = in ; ret[1] = out ;

Comment: This is a good answer, but "Section 3.3.5 of JNI programmer's guide has a good related example", link is dead as of 2016-05-18.

Comment: link to JNI Programmer's guide (Section 3.3.5 has the example mentioned by @CloudyTrees): http://barbie.uta.edu/~jli/Resources/Resource%20Provisoning&Performance%20Evaluation/85.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You have to use an object array for the outer array:

`jclass myClassArray = (*env)->FindClass(env, "[Ljava/lang/Object;");`

in a similar case with a 2D String array worked for me. Please also recognize the trailing semicolon in the string.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if this question is still relevant, but I think you simply forgot the semicolon at the end of your array class specification:

```
jclass myClassArray = (*env)->FindClass(env, "[Lorg/apache/s4/core/ShareStruct;");
```