# how to return array of Mat from JNI to Java

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk

How can I write my c++ JNI function so that it returns an array of Mat to Java code?
I am programming in Android environment, with the help of NDK to use also some functions of OpenCV.

My c++ function is:

```
 JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_micaela_myapp_MainActivity2_getFrames(JNIEnv* env, jobject object, jstring path)
{
    const char *str;
    str = env->GetStringUTFChars(path, NULL);   
    VideoCapture input_video;
    if(input_video.open(str)){
        cout<<"Video File Opened"<<endl;
    }else{
        cout<<"Video File Not Found"<<endl;
    }
    Mat image;
    Mat frameBuffer[1000];  
    int i=0;
    while(input_video.read(image)==true){
        image.copyTo(frameBuffer[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

In Java I have:

```
static{
    System.loadLibrary("myapp");
}
public static native void getFrames(String path);
```

This function now returns void and works properly. However, my purpose is to obtain the array frameBuffer from it, in order to use it in Java. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to allocate an array of equal size in Java, pass it to your native `getFrames()` function, and inflate the `Mat` objects individually using your frame buffer. Please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16012115/pass-an-array-of-mats-to-native-code) for an example of passing an array to native code, and [this one](http://answers.opencv.org/question/12090/returning-a-mat-from-native-jni-to-java/) for a way to inflate a Java `Mat` from a native one.

If you really need to create the array in native code and return it, please have a look at the `NewObjectArray` method that's available through JNI. ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11666821/array-of-object-array-2d-arrays-jni))

Comment: It's a good idea to allocate the array of Mat in Java and pass it to getFrames(). The problem is that I know how to pass a single Mat, but I don't understand how to pass an array of these to native code. In java I have to pass a Mat[N] object, but in cpp code how can I read it?

Comment: My apologies - the first link that I posted was wrong. I've updated my answer. The link has a good example of how to access a Java array. It doesn't pass the array to the native method directly, but instead uses `GetFieldID()` to reach across the boundary and access the Java array.