# Using AAssetManager_fromJava within plugin not directly called from Java VM (called from Unity)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm using Android NDK and need access to assets. A requirement for asset access seems to be obtaining an AssetManager reference.

Looking at the NDK samples (https://github.com/android/ndk-samples), the pattern seems to be:

- A `JNIEnv*` is passed into the func when called directly from the JavaVM, along with some `jobject`
- Use these to get `AAssetManager*` and then use this to open assets

That seems simple enough, except in my case, the functions are being called from Unity so I don't have access to either a `JNIEnv*` or `jobject`. Getting the `JNIEnv*` seems easy enough as I can make use of `JNI_OnLoad` to get access to a `JavaVM*` and then use that to get a `JNIEnv*` via `vm->GetEnv`. My questions about this are:

1) My understanding is that, an Android app can only have one instance of a Java VM. Am I safe to take the `JavaVM*` passed into `JNI_OnLoad` and save it for use in other function calls?

2) What about the `JNIEnv*`? Can I grab that once during `JNI_OnLoad` and save it, or should I grab a fresh one every time I need to use assets within a function? Is `JNIEnv*` something I need to explicitly free? (i.e. what's the lifetime/ownership situation with `JNIEnv*`?)

3) AAssetManager_fromJava also requires a `jobject` with the documentation (https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/asset#group___asset_1gadfd6537af41577735bcaee52120127f4) saying: "Note that the caller is responsible for obtaining and holding a VM reference to the jobject to prevent its being garbage collected while the native object is in use.". I've seem some examples that simply pass in an empty (native) string like `AAssetManager_fromJava(env, "");` - is that ok? I'd only be using the AssetManager for the lifetime of that call, and I could get a fresh one each time. (Again, is `AAssetManager*` a resource I need to manage, or am I just getting a reference to something owned elsewhere? The documentation seems to imply the latter.)

4) So given all the above, I'd probably do something like:

```
JavaVM* g_vm;
JNIEnv* g_env;

jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void* reserved) {
    g_vm = vm;
    g_vm->GetEnv((void **)&g_env, JNI_VERSION_1_6);  // TODO: error checking
    return JNI_VERSION_1_6;
}

void do_asset_stuff() {

    AAssetManager* mgr = AAssetManager_fromJava(g_env, "");
    // do stuff...

}
```

Is that reasonable? No memory/resource leak issues? Any issues with multi-threading?

Thanks!

EDIT: Seems like there are some threading considerations with `JNIEnv*`. See: [Unable to get JNIEnv* value in arbitrary context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991615/unable-to-get-jnienv-value-in-arbitrary-context?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Point-by point answer to your questions:

1. Yes, there can be [only one VM](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#javavm-and-jnienv) in Android. You are allowed to store this pointer or use [`JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#wp633).
2. `JNIEnv` pointers are tightly coupled to the thread they were created on. In your situation you will first have to [attach the thread to the VM using `AttachCurrentThread`](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#threads_1). This will fill in a `JNIEnv *` for you. Don't forget to `DetachCurrentThread` when you're done.

   Also note the caveat about [`FindClass`](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#faq:-why-didnt-findclass-find-my-class): you need to look up classes from the main thread or via the classloader of a class you looked up in the main thread.
3. The implementation of [`AAssetmanager_fromJava`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/native/android/asset_manager.cpp#61) is pretty clear: passing it anything other than an `AssetManager` object is undefined behavior. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11617834/1548468) shows one approach to grabbing the asset manager, another might be to call your own JNI function with a reference to the AssetManager object. Make sure to keep a global reference so it does not get GCed.
4. Given the above, it would probably look more like this:

```cpp
JavaVM* g_vm;
jobject cached_assetmanager;

jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void* reserved) {
    g_vm = vm;
    return JNI_VERSION_1_6;
}

void do_asset_stuff() {
    JNIEnv *env;
    JavaVMAttachArgs args = { JNI_VERSION_1_6, "my cool thread", NULL };
    g_vm->AttachCurrentThread((void **)&env, &args);
    AAssetManager* mgr = AAssetManager_fromJava(g_env, cached_assetmanager);
    // do stuff...
}

// Assuming you call `com.shhhsecret.app.storeassetmanager(mgr)` somewhere.
void Java_com_shhhsecret_app_storeassetmanager(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls, jobject am) {
    cached_assetmanager = env->NewGlobalRef(am);
}
```

Comment: thanks so much. Couple of follow-ups: 1) So I should call `DetachCurrentThread` at the end of `do_asset_stuff`? Do I need to do any other cleanup of `JNIenv*`? Can I just use `AttachCurrentThreadAsDaemon` instead?
2) Will I be able to use the `cached_assetmanager` across different threads once I have it?

Comment: 1) Call `DetachCurrentThread` if the lifetime of your app allows a normal stopping point. (no more work or some signal about quitting) Attaching your thread as a Daemon will allow the app to quit without quitting this thread, but that is not really a concern on Android. 2) Yes, in as much that the asset manager itself is thread safe.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to read a json file from Unity c++ plugin.
I had to extend UnityPlayerActivity to get assetManager as jobject.
The tricky part also was to find the correct path to the asset in the plugin:
I placed it into StreamingAssets/data and was able to read using this path 'data/myfile'

see my comment with the code:
[unity answers](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1679465/accessing-config-file-from-cc-android-native-plugi.html)

Seems Botje's answer is precise (pity, I did not have it earlier)

Comment: thanks! would it be possible to see the MyUnityPlayerActivity.java code?

Comment: yes, I attached it in a comment in the same [unity answers](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1679465/accessing-config-file-from-cc-android-native-plugi.html)

Comment: I can only see the native code? Not the Java code? But it's cool - I've managed to solve it without having to override UnityPlayerActivity, using Botje's answer

Comment: I added a comment 2 times there but cannot see it too. Here is its main part:
public class MyUnityPlayerActivity extends UnityPlayerActivity
{
    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
  loadConfigFile(assetManager);
   }
    public static native int loadConfigFile(AssetManager assetManager);
    static {
         System.loadLibrary("plugin");
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd post what I ended up doing in case it's of help to others...

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <android/asset_manager.h>
#include <android/asset_manager_jni.h>

JavaVM* g_JavaVM;
jobject g_JavaAssetManager;
bool g_Initialized = false;

jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void* reserved) {
    g_JavaVM = vm;
    return JNI_VERSION_1_6;
}

// call this once from the main thread in C# land:
extern "C" void UNITY_INTERFACE_EXPORT UNITY_INTERFACE_API NativeInit() {

    if (g_Initialized) { return; }
    g_Initialized = true;

    JNIEnv* env = nullptr;

    jint get_env_result = g_JavaVM->GetEnv((void **)&env, JNI_VERSION_1_6);

    if (get_env_result == JNI_EDETACHED) {
        jint attach_thread_result = g_JavaVM->AttachCurrentThreadAsDaemon(&env, nullptr);
        if (attach_thread_result != 0) {
            return;
        }
        get_env_result = JNI_OK;
    }

    if (env == nullptr || get_env_result != JNI_OK) {
        return;
    }

    jclass unity_player = env->FindClass("com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer");
    jfieldID static_activity_id = env->GetStaticFieldID(unity_player, "currentActivity","Landroid/app/Activity;");
    jobject unity_activity = env->GetStaticObjectField(unity_player, static_activity_id);
    jmethodID get_assets_id = env->GetMethodID(env->GetObjectClass(unity_activity), "getAssets", "()Landroid/content/res/AssetManager;");
    jobject java_asset_manager = env->CallObjectMethod(unity_activity, get_assets_id);
    g_JavaAssetManager = env->NewGlobalRef(java_asset_manager);

}
```

Now `g_JavaAssetManager` can be used in any thread to call `AAssetManager_fromJava`.